# convert code c# to vb.net delegate

Tags: c#, vb.net, delegates

I'm trying to convert the c # code of a sample code to vb.net but I could with the following line of code. it is an event, delegate. but I can not build a functional structure. someone could help me? 
thanks

```
Ellipse node = new Ellipse();
node.Style = nodeStyle;

node.MouseEnter += delegate(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
    if (selectedNode == null)
        node.BeginStoryboard((Storyboard)FindResource("NodeFadeIn"));
};

node.MouseLeave += delegate(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
    if (selectedNode == null)
        node.BeginStoryboard((Storyboard)FindResource("NodeFadeOut"));
};

node.PreviewMouseDown += delegate(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
    e.Handled = true;
    selectedNode = (Ellipse)sender;
};
```

Comment: Have you tried with [C# to VB.NET](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the AddHandler keyword in VB.NET to subscribe event handlers.  In VS2010, an anonymous method can be substituted with a lambda, like this:

```
    AddHandler node.MouseEnter, _
        Sub()
            If node Is Nothing Then
                node.BeginStoryboard(DirectCast(FindResource("NodeFadeIn"), System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard))
            End If
        End Sub
```

In VS2008 and earlier you'll need to write a little private method.

Comment: thanks for your help I have been very useful, just one last query, I have VS2008, as should be the code?